# Remove string from list and place it into another list if it does not contain certain characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So i have a list of names and i want to check this list to see if there are any that contain no vowels. If there are i want to remove them from the current list and place them into a no vowel name list.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
namesWithVowels = []

for name in names:
    originalName = name
    name = name.lower()
    if ('a' in name or 'e' in name or 'i' in name or 'o' in name or 'u' in name):
    namesWithVowels.append(originalName)

for name in namesWithVowels:
    if name in names:
        names.remove(name)
```